# .NET Core WebApp+LinuxContainer on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-web-app-for-containers

I created a simple .NET core web app using VS 2017 and added Docker support via VS 2017. I used the Linux OS type to run Docker locally. I was able to build the image and see the container running locally.
I then went about creating a new Azure private container registry and pushed the local image to Azure Container registry.
I then created a new App service, chose container option, Linux OS Type and selected the image from the Azure Container registry

and then set the startup file as "dotnet" .dll

The sample app has no authentication/authorization

But when I ran the application I always get

```
2018-11-18 07:25:49.003 INFO  - Starting container for site
2018-11-18 07:25:49.003 INFO  - docker run -d -p 60727:80 --name coreappwithcontainer_0 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=CoreAppWithContainer -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=4a540b6295ed1dd0d329bf772b30e20350c81c8fadb825a76720c725ee7912df -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 webapptesting.azurecr.io/samples/myfirstcoreappwithcontainer:latest dotnet /home/site/wwwroot/MyFirstCoreAppWithContainer.dll 

2018-11-18 07:25:50.663 ERROR - Container coreappwithcontainer_0 for site coreappwithcontainer has exited, failing site start
```

But for this, I do not get any other message for further troubleshooting.

Comment: i even changed the startup file option to multiple ways like adding the root folder and without the root folder like /app/MyFirstCoreAppWithContainer.dll and also just the dll name as well.

Comment: When you run your Docker image locally, does it run as you expect? Maybe you can set the startup in the image and without startup file when you create the Azure web app for Container.

Comment: Yes. It works locally. I tried removing the start up file as well in Azure

Comment: It's better to find the issue If you can provide your Dockerfile. Do you mind?

Comment: I was able to resolve by changing the build mode to "Release". In this mode, the app dll's were copied to the obj/docker/publish directly which was missing when the image was originally created in the debug mode. Thank you for the support and pointers

Comment: Do you mean the startup file missed in your image? Then how did the image work well locally?

Comment: If you have solved the issue, you can add an answer for others who look for this as you.